# Puppeteer is opening two windows, but I only want one (testing a chrome extension with puppeteer)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer, chromium

I'm working on running some puppeteer tests on a local chrome extension. Below is my set up for this - I launch puppeteer with some config settings, make a new page, and then navigate to the chrome extension. But for some reason, two windows are opening when I run this code.

The first window is the normal puppeteer chromium browser, where all of the subsequent tests run. Then there is a second window which opens the extension, and then just sits there and does nothing while the other tests run in the main window. I would like to not have this second window pop up.

In the `args` array of the code below, if I have either of the first two lines included, I get this two window behavior. Even if I remove one or the other, I get the same behavior. If I remove both, then I only get one window, but they are required for being able to run the extension in puppeteer.

So it's as if the args `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}` and/or `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}` are actually responsible for the opening of the second unnecessary window.

Does anyone know why this second window is opening, or more importantly know how to stop it from opening while still being able to load the extension in the main window?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 25,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--window-size=1480,1024`,
      `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`,
      `--enable-features=NetworkService`,
    ],
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1480,
      height: 1024,
    },
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'chrome-extension://dhlfjogdhekjoejlffmbpjkbablimdci/index.html',
    // 'https://google.com',
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're using `browser.newPage()` which creates a new tab.

To get the existing tab, use:

```js
const page = await browser.pages().then(e => e[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `await browser.pages()` already returns the list of pages existent. So you can just use the page at index 0, since a new page opens when you create a browser.

```
const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
```